# What does LOWERCASE_EXPANDED_TERMS do in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

In Lucene, when I index a field with upper-case letters, they are not found when doing a search.  Here's some sample code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //Create an index
        Directory index=new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(index, new IndexWriterConfig(new KeywordAnalyzer()));

        //Add a document to the index
        Document document=new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("path","/home/user/file1", Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new StringField("id","file1", Field.Store.YES));
        indexWriter.addDocument(document);

        //Add a document to the index
        document=new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("path","/HOME/user/file2", Field.Store.YES));
        document.add(new StringField("id","file2", Field.Store.YES));
        indexWriter.addDocument(document);

        //Close the index.
        indexWriter.close();

        //Create a query parser.
        StandardQueryParser standardQueryParser=new StandardQueryParser(new KeywordAnalyzer());
        StandardQueryConfigHandler config=(StandardQueryConfigHandler)standardQueryParser.getQueryConfigHandler();
        config.set(StandardQueryConfigHandler.ConfigurationKeys.ANALYZER, new KeywordAnalyzer());
        config.set(StandardQueryConfigHandler.ConfigurationKeys.ALLOW_LEADING_WILDCARD,true);
        config.set(StandardQueryConfigHandler.ConfigurationKeys.LOWERCASE_EXPANDED_TERMS,true);

        //Run a query
        Query query=standardQueryParser.parse("path: \\/HOME*","path");
        IndexSearcher indexSearcher=new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(index));
        TopDocs topDocs=indexSearcher.search(query,Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        //Iterate thru results
        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc:topDocs.scoreDocs){
            String id=indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc).get("id");
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
file1
```

I expected something like this:

```
file1
file2
```

If I set LOWERCASE_EXPANDED_TERMS to false, the result is:

```
file2
```

The [Lucene Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/standard/config/StandardQueryConfigHandler.ConfigurationKeys.html#LOWERCASE_EXPANDED_TERMS) for LOWERCASE_EXPANDED_TERMS says:
"Key used to set whether expanded terms should be lower-cased".  Can someone clarify exactly what this means?  Why are my upper-case values ignored?  Should I just do a .toLowerCase() on each value to make it searchable?

Answer (score 0):

`LOWERCASE_EXPANDED_TERMS` automatically lowercases wildcard, regex and fuzzy queries. This is where the expanded part comes in.  Wildcard, regex and fuzzy queries are expanded into multiple terms. These types of queries are not analyzed, so this setting serves as a stand-in for the lowercasing that your analyzer would otherwise be doing. A query clause that is analyzed (simple term or phrase queries, for instance) will not be affected by this setting at all.

It does *not* search for both upper and lower case terms in the index. If you want searches to be case insensitive, you should lowercase them at index time, either by analyzing with a `LowerCaseFilter`, or you could just use `String.toLowerCase()`, for StringFields.